# Iterating within a function

Tags: python, function, iteration

I've been working on this all day to no avail, I've spent all of about 4 hours researching a possible answer because I like to discover things on my own but I can't seem to move any closer.

Im writing a function that takes a string and with this string I have to convert each character to a symbol, excluding spaces and dashes.

I've tried creating a banking system for it as well but it seems like it only iterates over the first element, does this have something to do with return?

```
def get_view(puzzle): 
  for elements in puzzle:
      new_ string = elements.replace(elements, "$")
      return new_string
```

EDIT: 
I tried :

HIDDEN = "^"
new_string = ""

```
def get_view(puzzle):
    for elements in puzzle:
    new_string = puzzle.replace(elements, HIDDEN)
    return new_string
```

And now that returns

> > > get_view("abc")
> > >       'ab^'

Wtttfffff.

Comment: Woah, [this assignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876158/how-to-replace-a-string-in-a-function-with-another-string-in-python) was due **today**!?

Comment: No it's due this week. I'm just new to programming and want to understand whats happening.

Comment: Lol interesting, he doesn't go to my school but I'm sure most introductory python classes have the same material.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does have to do with [`return`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-return_stmt). When a `return` statement is encountered, the function process terminates; therefore, the `for`-loop of your function will always end on its first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to define what you want to convert each letter as. Let's take an example

`conversion_symbols = {'a':'$','b':'#'}` # fill in the rest yourself.

```
# then you have to loop over the string, give gives one character at a time, covert it and
# and add to your result string and then return the result string.

def get_view(puzzle):
  new_string = ""
  for element in puzzle:
      new_string += conversion_symbols[element]
  return new_string
```

Is this the approach that you were trying to get to?

Comment: When I try that I get the error:
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    get_view("abc")
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 16, in get_view
    new_string += HIDDEN[element]
TypeError: string indices must be integers END

where HIDDEN is the defined replacement.

Comment: HIDDEN = "^"

def get_view(puzzle):
    new_string = ""
    for element in puzzle:
        new_string += HIDDEN[element]

        return new_string
This is the code I used when that error came up