# Replacing characters in a string (Python)

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to replace a string in a function with another string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12876158/how-to-replace-a-string-in-a-function-with-another-string-in-python)

I want to enter any string with any type of character, and if the character is an alphabet, I want to replace it with "^" and get it printed.

For example, if my input is `replace('text-here')`, I should get the output as `"^^^^-^^^^"`.

I've tried using the following statement, but it just prints whatever my input was. Please help!

```
def replace(string):

    for x in range(len(string)):
        string.replace(string[x],"^")
    print(string)
```

I'm new to python, and don't know complex stuff. Please give me easy-to-understand answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> text = 'text-here'
>>> ''.join('^' if c.isalpha() else c for c in text)
'^^^^-^^^^'
```

I think this is easy to understand but just in case here is code that shows what it does more simply:

```
>>> def replace(text):
        new_text = ''
        for c in text:
            if c.isalpha():
                new_text += '^'
            else:
                new_text += c
        return new_text

>>> replace(text)
'^^^^-^^^^'
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Python's Regular Expressions library](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

Like so,

```
import re

re.sub('\w', '^', 'text-here')

# Outputs: "^^^^-^^^^"
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because string is immutable. string.replace(string[x],"^") returns a new object.

```
Modify 
string.replace(string[x],"^")
to 
string = string.replace(string[x],"^")
```

and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Now that your question is on "**but it just prints whatever my input was**", I would like to tell you that the method `str.replace` will return a new string instead of to replace the string in place.

```
>>> a = "foo"
>>> a.replace("foo","bar")
'bar'
>>> a
'foo'
```

So you need to do `string = string.replace(...)`